# Curious about the voting system and its implications

Tags: discussion, voting

I would like to know what the implications of downvotes are, and what the reasons may be.  I have been here many times to search/find answers, but this is my first time asking a question, and it was down-voted within an hour. I have no idea what I did wrong in my question, but it is certainly discouraging to have your first interaction with a site downvoted. I would love to know what was inappropriate, to prevent future problems.

Comment: I can only guess, but I'll wager that the reason for the downvote(s) on this question are due to an apparent lack of research. Spending a few minutes looking around, you probably would have found [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 10):

> what the reasons may be.

Quality control.

Downvotes tell a visitor that the post (question or answer) is not good.

> it is certainly discouraging to have your first interaction with a site down-voted

Yep - and it is also a learning experience. Try to see why it may have been downvoted and improve it.

> I would love to know what was inappropriate, to prevent future problems.

The downvote button has a tooltip:

"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". If a downvoter feels like sharing a reason, they may comment on why (but it is not required, given that we don't want to put obstacles in front of our first and best quality control measure).

Comment: Worth to expand a bit more about MSE itself and how downvoting here is different, assuming OP meant his first question here was downvoted. (and probably deleted, as I can't see other questions in their profile)

Comment: @ShadowWizard OP might be talking about SO where OP has one question that received one downvote.